# Exception in plugin Android Support when running on device

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just created a brand new android project with an single activity.

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.foo.bar">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="de.foo.bar.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.foo.bar"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

When I just build the project no error appears. However when I try to run it on a device I get following error:

Exception in plugin Android Support:

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.DefaultActivityLocator.getQualifiedActivityName(DefaultActivityLocator.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidActivityLauncher.launch(AndroidActivityLauncher.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doPrepareAndStart(AndroidRunningState.java:855)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartApp(AndroidRunningState.java:810)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartAppWhenDeviceIsOnline(AndroidRunningState.java:771)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doStart(AndroidRunningState.java:603)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.start(AndroidRunningState.java:579)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState$2.run(AndroidRunningState.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Any ideas what the problem is? I am using android studio 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it crashed because Android Studio can't locate the default / launcher activity, this occurs due to Android studio need to have defined a default activity, and you can do that adding  intent-filter to your manifest.

Your activity entry at AndroidManifest should look like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="de.foo.bar.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

You can have activities without intent-filter, but you need at least one with this filter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I tried to generate the signed APK for my project, so the solution is to add this in you build.gradle file in your project:

```
android {
...
   lintOptions {
      checkReleaseBuilds false
      abortOnError false
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction Alexis King, my English is very poor, sorry!